# Bootstrap Timepicker - Minute Intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I recently swapped from using jquery UI timepicker to using a timepicker found [here](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/timepicker/#jquery-plugins) as it appears jQuery UI is incompatible with Twitter Bootstrap.

I've managed to get datepicker and timepicker working but I lack some of the functionality of my old timepicker - the ability to control the steps in minutes. I wish to only allow the user to increase the minutes of the timepicker in 15 minute intervals. This worked flawlessly with jQuery UI using the following syntax:

```
$(function() {
  $('#div_id').timepicker({
    stepMinute: 15
  });
});
```

My current code, which calls the timepicker fine: (stepMinute gives no effect, likely incorrect syntax for this timepicker)

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#div_id').timepicker({
        stepMinute: 15
    });
});
```

I wish to emulate this using the bootstrap-friendly timepicker linked at the start of this question, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to change the plugin code you can use `change.bfhtimepicker` event ad increment/decrement hour and minutes by your step.

Alternatively, it will appear a little different because the UI, but you can switch to another bootstrap timepicker plugin that implements `minuteStep` feature.

Code:

```
$('#timepicker1').timepicker({
    defaultTime: 'current',
    minuteStep: 15,
    disableFocus: true,
    template: 'dropdown'
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/e3k37/

Ref: http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/

Comment: I did originally look at this plugin, but having it as 12 hour clock input would cause issues with making calculations based on the times. Looking at the options it seems i can disabled that by using `showMeridian: false`. If nobody can suggest a solution to my current datepicker, I will implement this. +1 for the suggestion.

Comment: Hi Irvin, i've all but given up on my original timepicker, it seems there is no equivalent to stepMinutes. If you can advise on making the timepicker you link so that the text field is disabled, forcing the user to enter a time via the timepicker. Ideally the timepicker should load on clicking the text field or the glyphicon. I will be glad to accept your answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just give "minuteStepping" option like below

```
$('.time').datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    use24hours: true,
    minuteStepping: 15,
    format: 'HH:mm'
  });
```

Comment: don't you mean "minuteStep"?

Comment: This is actually correct, but for the "datetimepicker" rather than the "timepicker".